# What is the size limit of each git repository created in azure devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-repo

What is the size limit of Git azure devops repository,in microsoft docs it says 10gb so this 10 gb is for all the repositories collectively or separately for each repositories .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

the above link from microsoft states that repositories should generally be no larger than 10GB but i am not clear whether its 10gb for all repositories collectively or separately.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to the service provider for an authoritative answer

Comment: The recommendation you're citing is per repository. I base this on the fact that common ways to understand that sentence would be similar to a sentence like "Cars should generally be no longer than 5 meters", which would obviously not mean that all cars in the world (or even owned by you) should be a *total* of less than 5 meters, but instead be per car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation thoroughly. They *recommend* that repos stay under 10 GB. A recommendation is not the same thing as a limitation.

> In uncommon circumstances, repositories may be larger than 10GB. ...
>   **For that reason, we do not have a hard block in place.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in doc its not clear whether this recommendation imposes on Repos of azure devops or the individual repositories created under repos.

Comment: There's nothing imposed. There is no restriction or limitation. The documentation explicitly states that.